# How do I add product attributes to the product page in WooCommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, code-snippets, elementor

I'm using WooCommerce and Elementor Pro. Is there any way to add specific product attributes (e.g. gross and net weight) below the Add to cart button?

It seems like an obvious thing but I haven't found options or snippets for it.

[image: example]

Comment: Your question is just about settings in WooCommerce and it is off topic on StackOverFLow… You didn't really search as there is a very clear WooCommerce documentation related to product attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you add attributes to product. Then you use this snippet in functions.php:

```
// maybe remove tab with attributes
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'remove_info', 100, 1 );
function remove_info( $tabs ) {
    unset($tabs['additional_information']);
    return $tabs;
}

// show attributes
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'summary_attributes', 35 );
function summary_attributes() {
    global $product;
    if ( $product->has_attributes() ) {
        wc_display_product_attributes( $product );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Setting Up WooCommerce Attributes**

- go to Products > Attributes
- Add the attribute name
- Slug will automatically be created, and we can leave the rest of these options untouched.
- Click “Add attribute” button and your attribute will be added.

**Configure The Attributes**

After creating attribute, now we can add different variation on your product. Click on the Configure Terms option.

- Enter the variation
- Add some short description
- Click on the add new tab

To understand it in a better way you can follow this [tutorial](https://pixelaar.com/how-to-add-and-manage-products-attributes-in-woocommerce/)